# laravel 5.2 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

source code 
the link i used is nav.blade.php :

```
{{link_to_route('register','Sign Up',null,['class'=>'signup-btn tbutton small'])}}
```

and routes.php

```
Route::get('create',[
    'as'=>'register',
    'uses'=>'RegistrationController@create'
]);
```

error :

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

```
1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

thanks

Comment: what is the current url that is throwing that error?

Answer (score 0):

`link_to_route` expecting "route name", such as `register.create` or `register.show`. Depends on your route.

if the url is using URI like `hello/world` you can use `link_to`